# What did the other 2 users choose as the close reason?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I'm looking at [this (off-topic) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344391/how-to-choose-right-hosting-for-your-web-project), which has now been closed, but only 3 of the 5 users are listed in the bullet points - why? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if the other reason were listed anyways…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other two users chose either duplicate, unclear what you're asking, too broad, or primarily opinion-based. (aka anything other than off-topic)

Why is this a bug? The users didn't choose off-topic, so why would they be listed as "chose off-topic?"

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks Doorknob! `:)` RE: your edit, it *does* say `put on hold as off-topic by: x, y, z, a, b`, although it's always said this on the close reason. The new bullet points confused me.

Comment: @DannyBeckett If a mod chooses a different reason, that reason appears as a separate bullet point.

Comment: @Daniel Except it doesn't - see the above screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

As Doorknob said in the other answer, the other users probably chose a different close reason. As I mentioned in a comment on Doorknob's answer, If a mod chooses a different reason, that reason also appears as a separate bullet point. I'm not sure how many non-mod users it takes to achieve a bullet point. Here's a screenshot example of a close with two bullet points, where a mod chose a different reason. It comes from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29985/1713).

[image: Screenshot of two close reasons]

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain to you. Here, all 5 users chose *off-topic*. In my example, 2 users chose something else, such as *too broad* or *primarily opinion based*; which does not generate extra bullet points (as shown in my screenshot).

Comment: @DannyBeckett How do you know? Did they tell you in chat or something?

Comment: I would add to this answer that "the other users probably chose a different close reason *that wasn't an off-topic close reason*", just to be clear. Hope this helps! :)